# Regular Expression - remove all characters inside <pre> tag

Tags: php, regex

I have html code and I want to remove all code inside "pre" tag using regular expression

For example

```
<pre>lorem ipsum</pre>
<p><strong>lorem ipsum</p>
<pre>lorem ipsum</pre>
```

and I want to get only

```
<p><strong>lorem ipsum</p>
```

I try this:

```
<pre>.*?</pre>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: [You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: Use Nokogiri as opposed to a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

A simple for the fun Javascript cleaner pre :

```js
var pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
for(var i in pres){
  pres[i].textContent = "";
}
```

```css
pre{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 border-radius: 8px;
 width:100%;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<pre>lorem ipsum</pre>
<p><strong>lorem ipsum</p>
<pre>lorem ipsum</pre>
```